# Swagger 3.0.1 server generator

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-3.0

When I generate a nodejs-server with swagger 3.0.1 in the online tool https://editor.swagger.io/ and try to `npm start` the project I always get the following error:

[image]

Error: Cannot find module './middleware/swagger.router'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short-term fix: you can get it to run until the maintainer of oas3-tools and Smartbear (for this server generator) fixes their respective parts.

PROBLEM A: oas3-tools build script isn't copying the 'middleware' over to the 'dist' directory.

To fix this:

1. Start your generated server (this will run npm install and create the `dist` folder in `node_modules/oas3-tools`)
2. Go into `./node_modules/oas3-tools` and manually copy the missing `src/middleware` to the `dist` folder.
3. Now that you have a `middleware` folder in your `dist` folder, run the following typescript compile command against it: `tsc dist/middleware/`

PROBLEM B:

The next issue is a typo on the path to the swagger document is incorrect.

To fix this:

1. In the index.js file of your generated server, change the string 'api/openapi.yaml' to 'api/swagger.yaml'

POSSIBLE EXTRA PROBLEM:

You may need to manually transpile your .ts files. Please see @Alex's comment below if you also run into this (i.e. `error TS6053: File 'dist/middleware/.ts' not found.   Found 1 error`)

---

- Swagger Editor bug posted here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/2086
- Oas3-tools bug posted here: https://github.com/bug-hunters/oas3-tools/issues/17

Comment: Just a note. Its also not picking up the port defined in the yaml file, so that will also need manually changing in the index.js

Comment: Great catch! That would have been today's task to catch that.

Comment: hey @Paulito.Bandito, I followed the steps but the 3rd step is not working for me. I tried the command `tsc dist/middleware/` but I get the following error: ```error TS6053: File 'dist/middleware/.ts' not found.


Found 1 error.```

Comment: I finally had to tsc every file one by one and it worked, idk why it wasn't letting me transpile the whole folder :S

Comment: Hi Alex, glad it worked out for you! Sry, didn't get a chance to respond until now.

Comment: I have the same problem as @Alex. Could you please update your answer? I think this is an important note

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of oas3-tools is 2.1.2 is screwed up. Use 2.0.2 for now.

```
oas3-tools : "2.0.2"
```