# Cannot find module 'oas3-tools'

Tags: node.js, swagger

Generated a nodejs-server stub with the [online editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) from swagger. After installing the packages, I ran `npm start` and I'm getting the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'oas3-tools'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/project/nodejs-server-server-generated/index.js:6:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

The `index.js` looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');

var oas3Tools = require('oas3-tools');
var serverPort = 8080;

// swaggerRouter configuration
var options = {
    controllers: path.join(__dirname, './controllers')
};

var expressAppConfig = oas3Tools.expressAppConfig(path.join(__dirname, 'api/openapi.yaml'), options);
expressAppConfig.addValidator();
var app = expressAppConfig.getApp();

// Initialize the Swagger middleware
http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
    console.log('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
    console.log('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
});
```

Closest thing I've found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59648179/swagger-3-0-1-server-generator) stackoverflow question, but this doesn't solve my specific problem.

The fix from https://github.com/bug-hunters/oas3-tools/issues/17 doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinning the version to `2.0.2` instead of using `^2.0.2` in `package.json` works. Use this until a new (working) version of https://github.com/bug-hunters/oas3-tools has been released.

From: https://github.com/bug-hunters/oas3-tools/issues/25

**EDIT**: Has been fixed in `2.1.3`
(https://github.com/bug-hunters/oas3-tools/issues/25#issuecomment-720482897)

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install oas3-tools
```

Install  oas3-tools From the above command and also you need to upgrade your NPM.

Use the following command to upgrade NPM:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not solve my problem. Upgraded npm to `6.14.4` and ran the command `npm install oas3-tools`. Still get the same error.